# On-line German tutors

Tags: learning, resource

I don't know if here is the best place to ask that, I need a German tutor to help me to communicate in German via chat and sometimes voice. Do you know any sites (free or not) which can provide me that? I've never use englishtown site, but if there are some sites in German of the same style, it would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A place not directly providing tutors, but where you can very probably find a penpal, is http://babbel.com. A second one is http://livemocha.com/

Comment: @c.p. yes, I know these sites, but I'm looking for something different, but thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Livemocha.com offers this kind of service.  You can chat with speakers of the desired language at no cost or you can pay for a tutor that works with you over a video chat like Skype.

Comment: I think there is no German tutor in this site

Comment: @user42912: [They say there is](http://livemocha.com/pages/languages/learn-german/) but to really find out we will have to register.

Comment: @Takkat there isn't :(

Comment: @Takkat What appears to me is French, English, Spanish and italian

Comment: @user42912: Did you register? On the page I linked to above they say *"**Live German Instruction** Private Tutoring Intensive one-on-one instruction with qualified native-speaking German teachers"*.

Comment: @Takkat I couldn't, I have to choice a language before register, I took a picture what happens: http://postimg.org/image/gk7dl6837/ee14daf4/

Comment: @user42912: oh - that indeed looks like they made a promise they can't keep atm. It may be a bug on their site however. Try to contact them directly for German support before you register.

Comment: @Takkat do you think this answer should be deleted by the owner of the answer?

Comment: In case they **really** do not offer a German service it should indeed be removed. Do we already know?

Answer (score 1):

I have been a member of Livemocha for a while.  I tried their tutoring service but didn't like it much. It was also quite expensive.

My best advice would be to look around on various forums, and see if you can find someone to tutor you over Skype for a reasonable cost.

You might also check here: http://www.wyzant.com/german_tutors.aspx